# MapServer Query Raster for Pixel Value at Point

Tags: raster, openlayers, wms, mapserver, query

I am working with a MapServer and a map file that is displaying a color-relief image.

```
LAYER 
    NAME            "sum"
    DATA            "sum.vrt"   
    TYPE            RASTER
    STATUS          ON
    DEBUG           0
    MASK            "masklayer"
    SIZEUNITS       PIXELS
    TOLERANCE       0
    TOLERANCEUNITS  PIXELS
END
```

[image]

*Note: I had it working with a PNG raster instead of the VRT with the TIF file also.*

**I need to be able to identify the pixel value at a point**

I did a WMS request GetCapabilities. It is saying that my `sum` layer is not queryable.

I tried to do a WMS call with the GetFeatureInfo and I made the bbox from the lat/lng of the point. I thought that would work but since the layers are not queryable, the request will fail.

What can be done to get the value at a point? Could it be done on the front end with open layers?

Comment: Are you doing some on-the-fly processing for your source files.with your .vrt file? Should GetFeatureInfo return the raw pixel values or processed ones?

Comment: You can get the pixel value of a layer in OpenLayers (even if the layer is hidden beneath another).  This demo https://jsfiddle.net/28r541b3/ uses mouse position but for a specific coordinate get the pixel using `map.getPixelFromCoordinate()`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know.