# Showing raster map pixel's information(pixel value) when clicked on the map in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, web-mapping

Here is my raster map code and I want see pixel information like pixel value from it when I click on the map:

```
const UnTiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity:0.9,
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        ratio: 1,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/shomal/wms',
        params: {
                 'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
              "STYLES": '',
              "LAYERS": 'shomal:geotiff_coverage',
              "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
        }
      })
      
    });map.addLayer(UnTiled);
```

Comment: When I open the raster map in openlayers in geoserver in the layer preview section, clicking on the info map in the table under the name geotiff_coverage shows the information in that table that
GRAY_INDEX is called I want

Comment: Do you want to use the pixel value similar to a DEM?  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/disable-image-smoothing.html

Comment: @Ian Turton The question is not related to GetFeatureInfo, a more relevant duplicate would be https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332008/mapserver-query-raster-for-pixel-value-at-point

Comment: @Mike - actually getFeatureInfo will do exactly what he wants (it's how the image preview works)